# 16 bit tiff decoder for flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, air, tiff

I am trying to open a 16 bit tiff image in my AIR app. What I have found is a baseline decoder which supports only 8 bit images. Here are my options:

- Extend its functionality to open 16
  bit images but I don't know how to do
  that and how trivial it is.

  Open my images as 8 bit but I need to
  do that automatically within Flex.
  Don't know how to do that either.
- I also need to support lzw
  compression for tiff, so please refer me some
  resources so I can develop that in
  case it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player, and therefore Flex, are limited in the supported image formats.  I thought it was just gif, jpg, and png actually.

To deal with other formats, I would suggest checking out [this project](http://blog.natebeck.net/2010/04/load-40-image-formats-into-flash-oh-and-its-open-source/) which made use of Alchemy to convert C code into an ActionScript SWC.  tif files are listed as supported and I assume that 'tif' and 'tiff' are the same.

Comment: ya, their thing doesnt support 16 bit tiff files but only 8 bit. Is it easy to extend the functionality to 16 bits. Any idea?

Comment: I doubt it would be easy to extend; as they converted a C library using Alchemy, an unsupported Adobe project that converts C to ActionSCript and provides no source code.  You can try using the same approach they did if you have a C library that supports 16 bit tiffs.