# Flex application for viewing tiles of tiff images

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I am writing a new application in Flex. I have to create a viewer which can view tiles from a tiff image. how can I write it. I am not able to find anything on the web. I could find openzoom but no tutorial. can anyone tell how to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300244/16-bit-tiff-decoder-for-flex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918759/as3-tile-map-rendering-with-1000s-of-tiles